# Why is there a difference in output between debugging profiles "IIS Express" and "MyApp"?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, iis-express

I am working on a Blazor web app "MyApp". I had some issue with styles and therefore deleted all the styles as long as they did not affect the effect I was examining. This is what stayed over:

```
<nav class="navbar ">
    <div>
        <ul style="margin:100px">
            <li>
                <div class="dropdown-menu show">
                    <a>testitem 1</a>
                    <a>testitem 2</a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

bootstrap provides

```
.dropdown-menu {
position: absolute;
top: 100%;
...}
```

**Running the app with debug profile "MyApp":**
Deleting `class="dropdown-menu show"` is what caused what I was looking for but commenting out the section in bootstrap.min.css did not have any effect. Also, I changed `top: 100%;` to `top: 80%;` with no effect.

**Running the app with debug profile "IIS Express":**
Commenting out the section in bootstrap.min.css and also changing `top: 100%;` to `top: 80%;` affect the output.

Why is there a difference and how can I prevent it?
What debug profile should I use? (I used IIS Express at the beginning but had the opposite effect that some things were obviously not updated when I changed the HTML code. So, I switched to MyApp).

Many Thanks

Comment: Unless you made changes to `launchSettings.json`, "MyApp" uses the Kestrel server, "IIS Express" uses exactly that - IIS Express to host the application. Read more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=windows

Comment: I did not change the `launchSettings.json`. Is there another explanation for the strange behaviour. Even more important: How can I avoid making changes, e. g. `top: 100%; to top: 80%;` without seeing them.

Comment: There seems to be something possibly caching the css - whether it be server-side or browser?

Comment: I created a new project and copied everything to it. So far it is working.

Comment: The strange behavior is back. I switched from Chrome to Edge and had no problems first but now the same happens. I reset Edge (Settings -> Reset settings -> Restore settings to their default values) what solves the problem. Is there a way to not cache the css? Note that this happens only with debug profile "IIS Express", not with "MyApp".